# How to apply custom scale other than 1?

Tags: modeling, particles, hair, scale

I want to keep the size of an object, but I need to make the scale of different objects uniform to keep the hair particle the same.
How to apply custom scale other than 1 without actually scaling the object?

Comment: Scale by 2 in _Object Mode_, go into _Edit Mode_ and scale by 0.5? (or any other combinations scaling by x and then scaling by 1/x)

Answer (score 1):

Just divide the object scale with target scale number, then apply scale to 1, then multiply the object scale with target number.